# Can we create a web application (web site) using WinJS?

Tags: winjs

I am trying out WinJS & would like to know if its possible to create a web application using WinJS.

Something that you would typically create using HTML5 + Bootstrap + JS framework (like AngularJS).

I need to create a Line of business that would be hosted on a server & can be accessed through any browser from any device.

I am thinking of considering WinJS because
- My primary audience would be on Microsoft devices & so in future if I need to create a Cordova wrapper I can easily create one.
- I would benefit from Microsoft support.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. As of April 2014, WinJS became an open source, cross-platform framework, no longer exclusive to Windows. It's fully licensed for use on the web, and work has been done to make it compatible with other frameworks. You can find info now on try.buildwinjs.com, specifically http://try.buildwinjs.com/#get that tells you the different ways to acquire libraries for your needs. This includes doing a custom build of a subset of functionality, which takes you to https://github.com/winjs/winjs-modules where the source actually lives.

You can find some details on the Sept 2014 release of WinJS 3.0 at http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/09/17/winjs-everywhere/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but to add, is it possible to create a web application (SPA) using just WinJS? Without using any other framework for routing etc. I was not able to find anything that would support routing in my SPA web app. Please help.

Comment: @ManStack Might I suggest using FREE visual studio 2013 and starting with a basic MVC application. That will take care of basic plumbing tasks such as routing.  Then use winJS to build your SPA application.

Comment: Look at WinJS.UI.Pages...that's the mechanism for SPAs. In addition to online docs, Chapter 3 of my free ebook Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Ed (http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2) goes into detail on the paging mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Sam - Kraig - I'll check WinJS.UI.Pages - but if you could suggest if this would serve the same purpose as routing in ASP.net mvc or AngularJS for a web site (not windows store app)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with routing, so I can't compare. I can only say that Pages is an HTML fragment loading mechanism that provides for "navigation" in a single-page context. If that's not sufficient, then you can use Angular or other frameworks for such purposes, and use WinJS for other features.